# LetsEncrypt TLS Cert invalid? "EVP_MD_size:message digest is null"

Tags: ssl, postfix, lets-encrypt

I am finding this in my logs for postfix, I'm using a LetsEncrypt certificate but I'm unable to find any useful information online about it. Does anybody know if this is a problem or something that isn't important?

```
postfix/smtpd[526]: warning: TLS library problem: 
error:060A209F:digital envelope routines:EVP_MD_size:message digest is 
null:crypto/evp/evp_lib.c:316:
```